# Explode to array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm dealing with this program,Here I'm trying to separate the string email,by ',',and then I'm storing in the array,then appending with 'city' in foreach..

```
$email='aa,bb,cc,dd';
$a=explode(',',$email);
//echo $a[2];
$result="";
foreach($a as $v)
{
     $result .= " city = '$v' ";
     echo $result;
}
```

I'm getting the result as

```
city = 'aa' city = 'aa' city = 'bb' city = 'aa' city = 'bb' city = 'cc' city = 'aa' city = 'bb' city = 'cc' city = 'dd'
```

but I want it to be,,

```
city = 'aa' city = 'bb' city = 'cc' city = 'dd'
```

Is my code wrong?..please guide me..

Comment: Don't put the `echo` in the loop. That's why it outputs the progressively growing list.

Comment: Seems like the rest of the squadron has just flown in.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `echo` out of the loop since you are building the whole string in the loop, this will echo the string every time.

```
$result="";
foreach($a as $v)
{
     $result .= " city = '$v' ";

}

     echo $result;  // move it here
```

Comment: Maybe I should put in the same answer too. (joking)

Comment: @user2810964 You know what to do.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky SO can be so funny sometimes hehehe (`+1`) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the result as per your code, you `echo` the result in each `loop` execution.

So for getting the final values inside $result, `echo` it outside the `loop`.

```
foreach($a as $v)
{
    $result .= " city = '$v' ";
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the string concatenation in the result

```
 $email='aa,bb,cc,dd';
$a=explode(',',$email);
//echo $a[2];
$result="";
foreach($a as $v)
{
     $result = " city = '$v' ";//changed $result .= " city = '$v' "; to $result = " city = '$v' ";
     echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are echo $rresult in foreach so your string or variable is repeat. Please try below code :

```
$email='aa,bb,cc,dd';
$a=explode(',',$email);

$result="";
foreach($a as $v)
{
    $result .= " city = '$v' ";     
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove string concate..

```
$email='aa,bb,cc,dd';
$a=explode(',',$email);
//echo $a[2];
$result="";
foreach($a as $v)
{
     $result = " city = '$v' ";  // remove string concate..
     echo $result;
}
```

Another way is *echo outside the foreach loop*...

```
$email='aa,bb,cc,dd';
$a=explode(',',$email);
//echo $a[2];
$result="";
foreach($a as $v)
{
     $result .= " city = '$v' "; 
}

echo $result; // echo outside the foreach loop
```

**Output**

```
city = 'aa' city = 'bb' city = 'cc' city = 'dd'
```